# Is it no longer possible to display multiple previews at the same time with the Xcode update?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I think I used to be able to view multiple previews at the same time, but now I can only view one at a time?

I have tried enclosing it in a Group, WidgetPreviewContext, PreviewDevice.
I could not find any buttons on the Preview that corresponded to it either.

**Environment**

Xcode: 14.3.1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was possible to show multiple previews in a single canvas but the ability to do so was removed in Xcode 14 unfortunately. Now you need to click on each individual preview in canvas in order to view them.

There is an option to show multiple devices for a single preview depending on the UI variants (color scheme, orientation, dynamic type)
[image]